# Temporary: ssh: connect to host failed: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, embedded, beagleboneblack

SSH is installed and daemon is running.

After i installed g_ether to enable ssh over usb (to a beaglebone black, arm based micro computer) i get this error for the first 2 mins at boot up time of the device. After 2mins i can ssh in.

My only thought is that there is a conflict w/ the device address or IP at startup. I've tried changing the IP to a few different things, didn't work. Tried to set the hw address using modprobe, didn't help.

Comment: Most likely the SSH service isn't running initially.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue since installing Ubuntu and have neverbeen able to resolve it; I'm guessing it has something to do with the router. The tail of my /var/log/dmesg does indicate some problem bringing up eth0; I don't know if this is related.

```
[   11.749371] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
[   11.752407] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1
[   11.752439] libphy: PHY 4a101000.mdio:01 not found
[   11.757500] net eth0: phy 4a101000.mdio:01 not found on slave 1
[   11.806816] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   12.020337] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   14.444492] init: plymouth-log main process (357) terminated with status 1
[   14.830502] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
[   14.830571] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   15.624303] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (409) terminated with status 1
```